# int pointer to void pointer to char array somehow?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm having trouble understanding the following code:

```
char arr[] = {0,1,2,3};
void *vp;
int *ip;

vp = arr; 
ip = vp;
```

How is it possible that the int pointer ip can point to an element of arr if the array itself it's char? As I understand, while defining the pointer it must the same type as the data it poins to, but why in this case is it possible?

Comment: You can convert any pointer type to another pointer type. But dereferencing the resulting pointer won't be meaningful.

Comment: Since you never dereference `ip` in this code, there's nothing wrong. But if you try to do `printf("%d", *ip);` the result is either undefined or implementation-defined, I'm not sure which.

Comment: Merely creating an `int *` pointer from the address of a `char` object can invoke undefined behavior.  Per [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):  "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: And if you were to then *dereference* that `int *` pointer and access the `char` array as if it were an `int`, you would be violating [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @Barmar *Since you never dereference `ip` in this code, there's nothing wrong.*  Not true.  If `arr` is not correctly aligned for an `int`, merely putting the address of `arr` in `ip` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Since this may cause undefined behavior, the compiler is not required to diagnose it. So you can do this without any compilation errors. A smart compiler may detect the problem and issue a warning, but it's not required.

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible that the int pointer ip can point to an element of arr if the array itself it's char?

It is not possible.  The code presented is valid, but the effect is not to store in `ip` a pointer to any element of array `arr`.  *By definition*, `ip` points to an `int`, and the elements of `arr` are not `int`s, so `ip` does not point to any of them.

> As I understand, while defining the pointer it must the same type as the data it poins to, but why in this case is it possible?

Because pointer values are not necessarily valid (for their types, or even generally).  The result of the code presented is not that `ip` points to a `char`, but that attempting to dererference its value produces *undefined behavior*.  The same would be true after `ip = NULL;`, though the undefined behavior resulting from evaluating `*ip` would likely be different in the two cases.

You can characterize that as `ip` not pointing to anything, though I suppose you will recognize that that's an incomplete description.  The effect of `ip = vp` is generally not the same as that of `ip = NULL`.

More broadly, it is essential to understand that pointers are their own kind of values, distinct from and not inherently connected to the objects, if any, to which they point.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
char arr[] = {0,1,2,3};
void *vp;
int *ip;

vp = arr; 
ip = vp;
```

can invoke undefined behavior as it is.

Per [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) (bolding mine):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. **If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.**

Note that no dereference of the pointer is necessary - merely creating a misaligned pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Since there's no guarantee that `arr` is properly aligned for an `int` value, undefined behavior can not be ruled out.

And if you were to actually dereference `ip` and access `arr` as if it were an `int` value, that would be violating [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and would always be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This code does "pointer punning". It is one of the way of using the binary representation of one type as another type.

In C it violates the strict alising rules and it is Undefined Behavior.

In your case (assuming 4 bytes `int`) the content of the `char` array is going to be interpreted as `int` value.

```
int main(void)
{
    char arr[] = {0,1,2,3};
    int *ip = (int *)arr;

    printf("%d - 0x%08x\n", *ip, *ip);

}
```

output

```
50462976 - 0x03020100
```

The hex value is easier to interpret as two digits of the number represent one byte in the memory. As you see the the number is "reversed" comparing to the representation in the memory. It is because PC computers are little endian and least significant byte is store first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

To avoid Undefined Behavior you should copy the array into the integer

```
int main(void)
{
    char arr[] = {0,1,2,3};
    int ip;

    memcpy(&ip, arr, sizeof(ip));
    printf("%d - 0x%08x\n", ip, ip);
}
```

> How is it possible that the int pointer ip can point to an element of
> arr if the array itself it's char?

In the end, any object (it does not matter what its type is) is just a bunch of chars (bytes) stored in the memory. Your pointer is referencing some location in memory.